# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ have the same cardinality iff m=n

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic, induction, natural-numbers

In the following proof, $\mathbb{Z}_n= \{ 1,2,....n \} $

[image]

After $g$ is defined , they defined the composition $gof$ and then they defined $h$ by removing the last ordered pair $(n+1,m)$ from the composition  $gof$  and then they applied the induction hypothesis on $h$.
There are a couple of thing I don't get in this proof

Why is g defined like that and why should I care about defining it anyway? It seems like unnecessary complication. Wouldn't it be simpler to say:  Ok, I have $f$, that goes from the first $ n+1 $natural numbers: $\mathbb{Z}_{n+1}$ to the first $ m $ natural numbers $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$, if I remove the last pair $(n+1,m)$ I get a function from the first $n$ natural numbers : $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ to the first $m-1$ natural numbers: $\mathbb{Z}_{m-1}$ and I can use the induction over $ n$:   $n=m-1$  $\rightarrow$ $n+1=m$

However I've found the same procedure in several books and they all do it in the same way. What  am I missing here?

Comment: Why does $f(n+1) = m$?

Comment: from the definition of $f$,    $f(n+1)$ has to take some value in $I_m=\{ 1,2,.....m  \}$, one possibility is that it equals m

Comment: It's one possibility, but it's not the only one. The proof is just arranging that to be the case.